# gitlab-ci runner's Docker Executor | How can I see docker container where the build is going on?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am newbie to `gitlab-ci`. I have set up gitlab runner on my private server with docker executor. When I merge new commit to my repo, the build is triggered. I can confirm that from web UI of `Gitlab`.
As I understood, the jobs are run on runner server itself so I guess docker container is created on my private runner server. But I can not see that container, when I do `docker ps -a` or I can not see even docker image which is used to create container.
Is there a way to check container/image running job? Or is there any mistake in my understanding?

And I can see job's logs on web console but can I see those logs on `CLI`?

Please correct me if I am wrong at any point.

Comment: Make sure the user you are running `docker ps` with has the permissions to view running containers. I am using the original gitlab-runner docker image with socket-sharing and I can see the container running at all times after starting (and registering it to GitLab). While the runner is doing jobs, I can see more entries in `docker ps`. They are visible as stopped in `docker ps -a` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

> when I do docker ps -a or I can not see even docker image which is used to create container.

That seems expected if you have activated the docker:dind service (docker in docker).

You would see your containers only with [Docker socket binding](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding) , where  any containers spawned by docker commands will be siblings of the Runner rather than children of the runner.

> By sharing the docker daemon, you are effectively disabling all the security mechanisms of containers and exposing your host to privilege escalation which can lead to container breakout.
>   For example, if a project ran `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)` it would remove the GitLab Runner containers.

Comment: I don't understand why I have to activate docker:dind service. I believe docker container is run on gitlab runner host, isn't it? If so, then the container should be visible after a build is triggered just by doing `docker ps -a` either dead or running.

Comment: @Rohanil SO you are using a shell executor? (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-shell-executor)

Comment: I am using [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html)

Comment: I see `--executor docker`  only in dind or socker binding.